# VMware vSphere SDK cloning VM into default Resource Pool

Tags: java, vmware, vsphere

I'm working on a system for cloning virtual machines. The system does not allow the user to select the Resource Pool where the VM will be cloned to. So I need to specify the default Resource Pool (called 'Resources'). Is this resource pool the same for all hosts in the datacenter? how can I get this default resource pool?

```
ServiceInstance vmwareServiceInstance = new ServiceInstance(new URL("https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/sdk"), "user","pass", true);
Folder rootFolder = vmwareServiceInstance.getRootFolder();

InventoryNavigator rootInventoryNavigator = new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder);
ResourcePool resourcePool = (ResourcePool) rootInventoryNavigator.searchManagedEntity("ResourcePool", "Resources");
```

in the case resourcePool gets one resourcePool called 'Resources", is this the first one that finds?
What I really need is the default resource pool for the host were the VM is going to be cloned. Is there any way to obtain this? The HostSystem object has no getResourcePool() method...

Thanks in advance

Diego

Comment: I suggest you to use the REST APIs which we developed rather than using the old SDK.

Comment: @Sambit thanks for the reply, sadly, the application has been developed using the sdk, any ideas as how to approach this issue using the sdk?